# Trouble getting the UITableViewCell for path [Xamarin.iOS]

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

There is pretty much simple piece of code to get all visible cells of the table:

```
var paths = TableView.IndexPathsForVisibleRows;
foreach (NSIndexPath item in paths)
{
    var cell = GetCell (TableView, item);
    if (cell != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("cell={0}", cell);
    }
}
```

The problem is that cell is always null. However, paths is not empty and contains correct amount of items. How this is possible?

Comment: It is not clear what GetCell is calling or where it is being called from

Comment: can you show us the GetCell implementation?